# Routes stopped working after updating Laravel. All

Tags: laravel

I know that the route system in Laravel 5 and later is different, but I was not ready for that. Upgraded to Laravel 7 and all routes stopped working for me.

The problem is in my views, in my project the route looks like this:

```
href="{{route('profile', ['id' => Auth::user()->nickname])}}"
```

And an error is returned to me that I did not pass an argument, although I did pass an argument.
Everything starts working if I fix it like this:

```
href="{{route('profile', Auth::user()->nickname)}}"
```

How do I fix this problem? It is very difficult to rewrite all the routes by hand, since there are thousands of them and most of the routes are of the form`/{param1}/{param2}/...`

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 7 it should also work with the key. I think something else is the problem, did u follow the Laravel upgrade guides?